# How do I get only indexed data in response?

Tags: solr

The JSON response from Solr looks like this by default:

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "q":":",
      "_":"1548243795257"
     }
    },
  "response": {
     "numFound":1,
     "start":0,
     "docs":[
      { <my data>}
```

If I add `omitheader=true` in they query parameters, it will remove the header from the response.
But how can I remove this line: response    :`{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[`

I am integrating Solr with AEM.

In the response I want only the index data.

Comment: Why do you want it to be removed? its useful info as you get to know the number of matching documents count ...if you go ahead with pagination then start would be useful...Start is the offset to start at in the result set. This is useful for pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without the JSON format, you can add query parameter *wt=csv*